# Are the services offered by the linux kernel implemented as kernel threads?

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, operating-system

Like in **process management** and **memory management**.

Are the *scheduler* and *memory manager* implemented as kernel threads that are run on the cpu the moment they are needed? If not, how does the kernel treat them?

Are they like processes, tasks, or some line of code that gets executed when needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some are, some aren't.  The terms "process management" and "memory management" are kind of broad and cover a fair bit of kernel code.

For memory management, a call to `mmap()` will just require changing some data structures and can be done by the current thread, but if pages are swapped out it will be done by `kswapd`, which is a kernel thread.

You might consider the scheduler a special case: since the scheduler is responsible for scheduling all threads, it itself is not a thread and does not execute on any thread (otherwise it would need to schedule itself... but how would it schedule itself, if it had to schedule itself first in order to do that?).  You might think of the scheduler as running directly on each processor core when necessary.

Comment: +1 just for the last paragraph.  I knew how the OS scheduler/dispatcher worked until I read that:)

Comment: So, is it safe to assume that the kernel is like a big blob of code and the scheduler, memory manager, interrupt handler, etc... can be thought of as part of that code that gets executed when needed?

Comment: You can think of any program as a "big blob of code", so it's true but not a particularly useful abstraction.  "The memory manager" is really made of a few different parts, like the swapper, the fault handler, and the page cache.  The swapper is a thread, the fault handler is an interrupt handler, and the page cache is data.  Since the swapper is a thread it gets executed whenever scheduled.  Since the fault handler is an interrupt handler it runs directly in response to page faults.